# can't connect to virtual machine linux created by puppet

Tags: azure, openssl, puppet, putty, azure-virtual-machine

I'm trying to automate my infrastructure using puppet with Azure.

I've created my puppet master using puppet enterprise VM from gallery on Azure. After that, I've generated a certificate running the following commands:

```
sudo openssl req -x509 -nodes -days 365 -newkey rsa:1024 -keyout cert.pem -out cert.pem
sudo openssl x509 -inform PEM -in cert.pem -outform DER -out cert.cer
```

Then, I've uploaded my cert file to Azure Management Portal and finally, I've create a VM with the following command:

```
puppet azure_vm create --management-certificate /tmp/cert.pem --azure-subscription-id=xxxxxx --image 0b11de9248dd4d87b18621318e037d37__RightImage-Ubuntu-12.04-x64-v13.4 --location 'west us' --vm-name puppetslave --vm-user xxxx --password xxxxx  --puppet-master-ip 23.102.xxx.xxx
```

Finally, I've exported my private key using PuttyGen and I'm using it to connect to my new linux vm. Unfortunately, I'm getting the following error:

> server refused out key

And I don't know why. I'm stuck at this point and don't know how to proceed.

Comment: This looks more like a ServerFault question.

Comment: I believe that it's something with puppet. I've tried get in touch with MSOpenTech but they didn't help me yet.